# MongoDB: how to compare $size of array to another document item?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB: how to do something like this, both in mongo console and via JavaScript, Node.js:

```
db.turnys.find( { users:{$size:seats } } )
```

turnydb.turnys looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "gId": "5335e4a7b8cf51bcd054b423",
    "seats": 2,
    "start": "2014-03-30T14:23:29.688Z",
    "end": "2014-03-30T14:25:29.688Z",
    "rMin": 800,
    "rMax": 900,
    "users": [],
    "_id": "533828e1d1a483b7fd8a707a"
  },
  {
    "gId": "5335e4a7b8cf51bcd054b423",
    "seats": 2,
    "start": "2014-03-30T14:23:29.688Z",
    "end": "2014-03-30T14:25:29.688Z",
    "rMin": 900,
    "rMax": 1000,
    "users": [],
    "_id": "533828e1d1a483b7fd8a707b"
  },
...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **real** problems with the acceptance of using the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator in **any** sort of way. Especially considering some of your "later" questions that have been raised. You **need** to **read** the manual page on this operator (as given in the link).

The short points:

- The [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator invokes a **full collection scan** in order to do it's comparisons. This is **bad** news in "real world" cases since there is **no way** to "constrain" this search to use an index in any way, and thus reduce the working set.
- By nature, this operator invokes "arbitrary JavaScript execution". And this means two things. **1**.) Every document **must** be expanded from it's native BSON form into the "JavaScript" object form (at a **cost**) for each comparison. **2**.) You are invoking a "JavaScript" interpreter, that is **not** native code, for each and **every** comparison.

[**One**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22749357/2313887) of the answers gave you **valid** warnings on this, though it did not provide you with an actual answer. So here it is:

As stated, **yes** you **should** actually be keeping a "count" of the "array" elements within your document if this is important to you. But whilst you may have seen this as valid, the **proper** comparison is done as follows.

So let us assume you did use `$inc` as suggested to keep a `total_users` field in your document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "gId": 1,
        "alloc": { "$eq": [ "$total_users", "$seats" ] }
    }},
    { "$match": { "alloc": 1 } }
])
```

Where *essentially* you can [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) all the fields you want in the document, just as long as you make the comparison as shown with the "alloc" field by simply doing a "logical" comparison as shown with the [**`$eq`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) operator.

In future releases ( very soon as of writing ) you even get to find out the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of an array within the "aggregation" operation. So *"instead"* of keeping a counter on the "array" members you can do this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "gId": 1,
        "alloc": { "$eq": [ { "$size": "$users" }, "$seats" ] }
    }},
    { "$match": { "alloc": 1 } }
])
```

But naturally that will come with a "cost", so **still** the best option is to keep that "counter" on your document, depending on your needs.

While **both** approaches here do *still** result in a "collection scan" (in this context since there was **no** other $match condition), the end result will be **many** times faster than the "JavaScript" execution that was shown in other answers.

Use the *"native code"* methods as a best practice solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `$where` query:

```
db.turnys.find({ $where: "this.users.length == this.seats" })
```

Answer (score 2):

While you could use `$where` as proposed by others in order to do cross field comparisons, I'd not recommend it if possible:

No indexes can be used for this search. Mongo will scan **every** document and execute a JavaScript expression against each one to do the cross-field comparison. This will be an expensive and slow operation.

Coming in the next version of MongoDB (2.6), you'll be able to to use the `$size` [operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) in an aggregation which could compare two fields.

But, for the best performance, I'd recommend you store a materialized boolean that would store whether the number of elements in the `users` array is equal to the number stored in `seats`. You can easily store the number of current users using `$inc` (positive and negative) if you don't want to fetch the entire array in order to get the count and do the comparison against the field "seats".

If you must use [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), I'd recommend you try to do some filtering if possible that might help avoid a full table scan. Maybe date ranges, or checking whether the `users` array is empty, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator with a String that contians a JS expression or using directly a JavaScript function:

```
> db.turnys.find(function() { return this.users.length == this.seats })
```

Answer (score 1):

You Could use any one of the following ways

```
db.flight.find({"$where":"function() { return this.users.length == this.seats}" })
```

or

```
db.turnys.find({ $where: "this.users.length == this.seats" })
```

or

```
db.turnys.find(function() { return this.users.length == this.seats })
```

These all will serve your purpose but the thing is efficiency and "$where" queries should not be used unless strictly necessary: they are much slower than regular queries, so try and avoid queries with "$where".