# MongoDB: how to do $or with $where (it doesn't do logical OR)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can we use $or with such a $where clause?

This query should always be returning all records (because of the date in 2015), but it doesn't return anything.

In parts, it works, but when trying to apply the $or to the Date or $where, it doesn't work as intended.

Thanks to Sammaye to fixing my previous version of this, to the following (still not working though):

```
db.turnys.find({
       $or:[
            { start:{
               $lte:new Date("2015-03-31T09:52:29.338Z")
            } },
            { $where:"this.users.length == this.seats" }
       ]
});
```

How can I accomplish the intended $or?

Here is a sample of the turnys collection:

```
[
  {
    "gId": "5335e4a7b8cf51bcd054b423",
    "seats": 2,
    "start": "2014-03-31T08:47:48.946Z",
    "end": "2014-03-31T08:49:48.946Z",
    "rMin": 800,
    "rMax": 900,
    "users": [],
    "_id": "53392bb42b70450000a834d8"
  },
  {
    "gId": "5335e4a7b8cf51bcd054b423",
    "seats": 2,
    "start": "2014-03-31T08:47:48.946Z",
    "end": "2014-03-31T08:49:48.946Z",
    "rMin": 1000,
    "rMax": 1100,
    "users": [],
    "_id": "53392bb42b70450000a834da"
  },
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about showing some of your documents?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js to MongoDB: find by Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747810/node-js-to-mongodb-find-by-date)

Comment: That's not how to format a $or query, that is actually a $or clause with an $and in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$or`s do not work that way, in reality what you need is:

```
db.turnys.find({
   $or:[
        { start:{
           $lte:new Date("2015-03-31T09:52:29.338Z")
        } },
        { $where:"this.users.length == this.seats" }
   ]
});
```

That will now create an `$or` query with two clauses. Each element of the `$or` array is classed as a `$and`ed clause.

Comment: @mylord sorry I didn't get back, was a bit busy, glad to hear it works :)

Answer (score 0):

As I referenced to you on your [**other question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22763129/2313887), the use of the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator **should** be avoided as shown in the given reasons there.

So again as shown what you **should** be doing is "allocating" a `total_users` value within your document, using the $inc operator on updates. But your "query" should look like this with the use of [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "gId": 1,
        "start": 1,
        "alloc": { "$eq": [ "$total_users", "$seats" ] }
    }},
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [ 
           { "alloc": 1, },
           { "start": { "$lte": new Date("2015-03-31T09:52:29.338Z") } }
        ]
    }}
])
```

Or even possibly use the "array size" form that was mentioned with more **recent** versions ( still to be released as of writing ) of MongoDB.

But also to "clarify" you **need** to make sure your "test" operations are actually valid.

Comment: When I try this in the mongo shell (after replacing gId with a real gId, I get: 
JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
Any ideas? What tool might I use beside shell?

Comment: @mylord No. $project with `1` as a value means "include" this field. So you either use `1` for `true` or in this field you actually just use the field value as in `$gId`

Comment: Oops, I'd need to, for one, add total_users.

I want to +1, but still can't :/

Comment: @mylord Point is, apart from whatever other problems you might have in your logic, you should not accept the usage of $where (and I did already point this out) because it is not good news for your application. Sort out your general selection issues first. And stay with the recommended usages for handling the length of an array and comparing.